Updating KLN 900 Unit database
I have been trying to update KLN 900 database using the usb cable however getting the msg "Data Loader not ready" on KLN unit and on laptop screen "Not responding" with data-loading not moving past 0%. I have tried to trouble shoot as per the guidelines of Honeywell, still no joy. Can anyone help through this. COM port 4 is being used.

This is off-topic. I don't see anything related to aircraft or aviation in your question. Maybe try SuperUser.SE?

@AircraftEnthusiast007: This is not off-topic, it's about a GNSS based instrument providing aeronautical information. Whether it can be answered without asking for additional details is another question.
